# How to access specific data retrieved as JSON from a php file through AJAX get request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a PHP file from which I am trying to retrieve results in JSON format and access it in another html page through AJAX get request. I'm able to access the entire data but I'm not been able to access the individual data fields of JSON data. Here is the actual data when printed on the console :

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Amit","age":"26"},{"id":"2","name":"Alka","age":"26"}, 
{"id":"3","name":"Pragati","age":"25"}]
```

Now, my question is how do I append only the name of the first entry of JSON data received ? data[0].name does not seem to work.

Here is my Javascript code :

```
<script>
    // This script illustrates the use of load function in Jquery.
    let btn = $('button');

    btn.click(function(){
        $.get("query.php", function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            $('.dummy').append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is how my 'query.php' file looks which is used to convert SQL query result into JSON format.

```
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM sample")) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $myArray[]=$row;
   }
echo json_encode($myArray);
}
```

Comment: Found the solution : let ob = JSON.parse(data), then I was able to access individual fields for the JSON object.

Comment: Is the response just a string or an actual object? If you file isn't sent with a proper content-type header (eg `Content-Type: application/json`) jQuery won't know to automatically to parse the incoming string as JSON and therefore all you have is a string and not a object

Comment: Use `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()` and you don't have to use `JSON.parse()` yourself. Benefit also is if invalid json gets returned will trigger internal error handler

Comment: It is an object I guess, no where in the code I specified the format for data while retrieving it from 'query.php'. I simply used 'get' request with a url. JSON.parse(data) did work for me though and now I am able to append only the name field contents of JSON data into some html div through a loop.

Comment: Yeah, getJSON() helped, No more parsing required. Thanks a lot!